# If $\sum a_m$ exist then $\sum a_{2k}$ need not exist.

Tags: sequences-and-series

If $\sum a_m$ exist then $\sum a_{2k}$ need not exist

I am unable to find a counter example of the above fact. Is it possible?

Comment: $\sum(-1)^n/n$.

Comment: By exists, do you mean the sum as $m$ goes to $\infty$?

Comment: Yes $m$ goes to $\infty$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HINT: Use a conditionally convergent alternating series. A very simple one works.

Comment: Got it brian ...

Comment: @KprimeX: Excellent.